# What does (:) do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've tried looking it up in hoogle and other various haskell dictionaries, but I can't find it. I was under the impression that it prepends, but I'm starting to see it in ways I haven't before and I've started second guessing myself.

For example, this is one of the questions that I don't understand:

(3 points) Fill in the blank with a pattern such that fun1 [(5,6),(7,8)] returns
5 and fun1 [(10,20),(30,40),(50,60)] returns 10:

and the answer is apparently:

```
         ((y,_):_)
  fun1 _____________ = y
```

But I am so confused by this. I understand that the underscores mean that you don't really care about what the types of those are, but I don't understand what the (:) does in this answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the other answers correctly explain what `:` is they don't quite answer the question - in the answer you have in your question `:` isn't used as a function, but as a constructor to pattern match on. `fun (x:xs) = x` means "if the argument is of the format (x:xs) give me the x". Pattern matching is used to "pull apart" complex types based on their constructors in Haskell.

In particular, since `:` is a list constructor you can pull apart lists with `:`

(conceptually list is defined as `data [] a = [] | (:) a [a]`, although you're not gonna get this to compile because it's builtin syntax).

A non list example: We could define a datatype `data F a b = A a | B b`. This would create a type `F` that's parameterized with two types `a` and `b` and two constructors `A` and `B` with the types `a -> F a b` and `b -> F a b` respectively.

You could then write functions that use pattern matching to get at the contained values, like

```
isA (A _) = True -- this value was constructed with A, so it is an A
isA (B _) = False -- this value was constructed with B so it is not an A
```

or

```
getA (A a) = a -- this value was constructed with A so we can get an a out of it
getA (B _) = undefined -- ohps! We can't get an a back here cause we don't have one!
```

Comment: So the answer is just picking apart the different sections of the list of pairs so that y = the first number in the first pair of the list?

Comment: yes, that's what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

It is a List constructor function. It is used for prepending any value in front of the list.

```
ghci> 2 : [3,4]
[2,3,4]
```

It is just another Haskell function. You can also see it's type in ghci:

```
ghci> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Regarding your question, the answer is like this `((y,_):_)` because it is being used in pattern matching. The first `_` is the second element of the pair and the second `_` pattern matches a list.

This may help you:

```
ghci> (5,6):[(7,8)]
[(5,6),(7,8)]
```

Comment: Right, so it just prepends whatever comes before it onto whatever comes after it?

Comment: @user3046635 Kinda. It takes a value of type `a` and prepends it on a list of type `[a]` if that's what you meant.

Comment: So then how does the answer to that question work? I don't see why the (:) is there because there is no list to prepend y to.

Comment: @user3046635 Updated with some explanations.

Answer (score 3):

`:` is the list constructor of type `a -> [a] -> [a]`. It is usually used infix. but you can use it as prefix if you surround it with parentheses as you did. Just like any infix operation. (E.g. `(+) 4 5 == 4 + 5`)

So `(:) a as` is the same as `a:as`

Every constructor in Haskell can be also used do deconstruct a value of the type if constructs in a pattern match:

```
f x:xs = xs
```

would for example define a function that takes a non empty list and returns the tail. It would fail on an empty list because the empty list is constructed by the nullary constructor `[]`. You could make `f` total by adding that second constructor to the match.

```
f [] = []
```

I guess your confusion comes from the fact that in haskell there is syntactic sugar that allows you to write lists in a more convenient way. Instead of `(1:(2:(3:[])))` you can write `[1,2,3]` which is expanded into the former by the compiler.

Comment: Right, but I don't see how that answer works if (:) is a list constructor used to prepend a variable of type a onto a list of type a.

Comment: great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers of what `(:)` function does, please, bear in mind that in the context of your question `:` is used as a deconstructor.

It is better to view `(:)` as a constructor. Then, just like any other data constructor, it can be used to introspect the contents of the value. Examples are:

```
f (Just x) = x -- extracts the value wrapped into Maybe a
f (x:_) = x -- extracts the value wrapped into a list, [a]
f ((x,_):_) = x -- extracts the value wrapped into a tuple in the list of tuples
```

In all these cases `Just`, `:` and `(,)` are constructors. The same syntax can be used to construct or deconstruct the values - depending on the context of the expression. Compare:

```
f x = Just x -- wraps x into Maybe a
f x xs = x:xs   -- wraps x into a list, [a]
f x y z = (x,y):z  -- wraps x into a tuple in the list of tuples
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand what `fun1` does, let's first look at another function:

```
f (x:xs) = x
```

If you pass this function a list such as `[5,12,33]`, it will match `x` to `5`, and `xs` to [12,33]. The function just returns `x`, i.e. the first element. So this function is basically the same as `head`. Since we don't actually use the value `xs`, we can rewrite the function as:

```
f (x:_) = x
```

Now let's look at `fun1`, but a slightly modified version.

```
fun1 ((y,z):xs) = y
```

If we pass this function the list `[(5,6),(7,8)]`, it will match `(y,z)` to the pair `(5,6)` and `xs` to `[(7,8)]`. So now `y` is `5`, and that's the value we return. Again, since we don't use `z` or `xs`, we can write the function as:

```
fun1 ((y,_):_) = y
```